# How to get the confidence interval (95%) value in label for a geom_smooth correlation plot with `stat_poly_eq(method= "lm")`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, confidence-interval

I was computing the correlation plots for my data. But, I need the CI 95% values for the correlation coefficients. I tried to add after stat(conf.int.label)code as in label:

```
Kan.PS_moc_plot <-Fnlcor_df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x= PSKannada, y= MOC))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = TRUE, alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_point(size =2)+
  stat_poly_eq(method = "lm",
               aes(label= paste(after_stat(rr.label), after_stat(p.value.label), after_stat(conf.int.label), sep = "*\",\"*")), label.x = "right", label.y = "bottom",
               size=4, family = "Palatino") + 
  labs(y=" MOC Median RT diffecrence (sec)", x="Kannada Phoneme Segmenation")+  
  facet_wrap(.~paste("Age Range:", AgeRange) + 
               paste("Group:", Group)) + 
  theme_classic() 

Kan.PS_moc_plot
```

**but I got this error**

`` geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x' Error in `stat_poly_eq()`: ! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics. ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer. Caused by error in `after_stat()`: ! object 'conf.int.label' not found Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred. ``

**How to get the CI 95% values? The 'se = TRUE' will only plot the CI value shade on the graph but I need to report CI values along with the R squared values**

Thank you for your timely help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`stat_poly_eq` doesn't calculate confidence intervals for each coefficient (you can use the `debug` mode to show what's in it if you follow the vignettes in `?stat_poly_eq`). I think the smoothest way would be to calculate coefficient of interest externally and add in:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

model <- iris |>
  lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = _) 

coef(model)['Sepal.Width']
#> Sepal.Width 
#>  -0.2233611

coef_label <- model |> 
  confint() |> 
  _['Sepal.Width',] |> 
  sprintf("%.2f", x = _) |> 
  paste(collapse = " to ") |> 
  paste0("paste(beta[1], \" = ", sprintf("%.2f", coef(model)['Sepal.Width']), " (", x = _, ")\")")

iris |>
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  stat_poly_eq(
    method = "lm",
    aes(label = paste(
      after_stat(rr.label),
      after_stat(p.value.label),
      coef_label,
      sep = "*\", \"*"
    )),
    label.x = "right", label.y = "bottom", size = 4
  )
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

### Edited answer - using `geom_text`

You can do the same for each group and plot it on a faceted graph using `geom_text`. I've removed the `stat_poly_eq` for clarity (as they're hard to get not overlapping and they don't quite paste together in facets)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

gap_data <- gapminder |> 
  filter(continent != "Oceania", year == 2007) |> 
  mutate(gdpPercap = gdpPercap / 1000)

coef_labels <- gap_data |>
  nest(data = -continent) |>
  mutate(model = map(data, \(data) lm(lifeExp ~ gdpPercap, data = data)),
         coef_label = map_chr(model, \(model) {

           # This code is the label-pasting code from above
           # Creates a separate label per facet

           model |>
             confint() |>
             _['gdpPercap', ] |>
             sprintf("%.2f", x = _) |>
             paste(collapse = " to ") |>
             paste0("paste(beta[1], \" = ",
                    sprintf("%.2f", coef(model)['gdpPercap']),
                    " (", x = _, ")\")")

         })) |> 
  select(continent, coef_label)

gap_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_text(data = coef_labels,
            aes(x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = coef_label),
            hjust = 1,
            vjust = -1,
            parse = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~ continent, scales = "free") +
  xlab("GDP per capita ($1,000s)")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer with clear illustrations. I'm very much hopeful about using this techin to solve this. But, currently my data set has sub-grouping variables (for example, I have responses from Two groups within group variable and  two ages (adult and children) within AgeRange variable. For this, I had used stat_poly_eq command and added facet_wrap two find the vales for creating 4 graphs. Now, how to coef_labels for 4 groups separately? Could you please add on the modified codes to this??

Comment: I've put some amended code up to try out if that helps?

Comment: Thank you very much, Andy!! These codes were helpful, except the pipe/place hoder used here showed some glich at the begining but rest every thing worked perfect.